# React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually with BrowerHistory

Tags: javascript, react-router

I'm using React-route and I know there's a similar question asked before.

[React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually)

But I still can't understand this topic. I mean, if my code is using BrowserHistory I get cannot GET error when refreshing the page. Then if I change the BrowserHistory to HashHistory, it works fine. Why is that happened? What is the difference between them?

Thanks

Comment: sounds like your server-side aspect of the router's URL isn't working. you do have a server behind all your app's URLs right? in short, for that style of history to work, the pages need to come up without javascript being enabled.

Comment: I just use gulp to run it on my localhost, may this cause the problem?